# Помогите написать код, где выводится по 5 строк из БД  на PHP

Tags: php, sql

В БД есть запрос "SELECT id_t, theme, msg, datetime FROM topic order by id_t DESC LIMIT 0,5". Здесь я вывожу последние 5 записей, но как мне обратиться из PHP чтобы пользователь мог нажимать на кнопку и с каждым разом выводить еще по 5 строк.

Comment: Гуглите постраничную навигацию на PHP. Думаю, это как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо Всем за советы и понимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['lim'])){
    $options = array(
        'options' => array(
            'default' => 0, // значение, возвращаемое, если фильтрация завершилась неудачей
            // другие параметры
            'min_range' => 0
        ),
        'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL,
    );
    // Проверяем является ли переменная lim коректным целым числом. Если нет то функция вернёт значение по умолчанию (default = 0), и пользователю выдаст результат для первой страницы
    $lim = filter_var($_GET['lim'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);

}
else{
    $lim = 0;
};
// Дальше в свой запрос подставляйте полученую переменную.
"SELECT id_t, theme, msg, datetime FROM topic order by id_t DESC LIMIT ".$lim.",5"
// Для управления генерируйте ссылки формата
page.php?lim=5
page.php?lim=10
page.php?lim=15 // и тд.
```

как то так.

Comment: Требовалось немного не так, но Вы навели меня на новую мысль для решения. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: А как? дайте больше информации постараемся помочь)

Comment: Вы мне и так очень помогли, я уже решил свою задачу)

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, N - счетчик уже просмотренных записей, а Id - primary key.

Тогда:

```
SELECT TOP (N+5) * FROM Table
WHERE Id 
   NOT IN(SELECT TOP N Id FROM Table);
```

Хотя это, конечно, коряво.